# A bank has to give 5 positions for 15 candidates

Tags: combinatorics

A bank must give 5 different positions to 15 people: 7 men and 8 women.

> *Question 1:*
>
> In how many ways can the jobs be given if there must be at least 3 women selected?
>
> Question 2:
>
> In how many ways ways can the jobs 1,3 and 5 be given if they can't be given to 3 people of the same gender?

**Attempt of 1:**

1) Choose 3 women from 8: $\binom83$.

2) Choose 3 jobs from 5 for these women: $\binom 53$

3) Permute the 3 women between those jobs: 3!

4) There's 2 jobs left for 12 people : $12 \cdot 11$

Answer: $\binom83\binom53 3! \cdot12\cdot11$

I need some tips for 2, I couldn't solve it in a similar manner...

Comment: Thanks! I added a second question I couldnt solve.

Comment: Suppose the women are {A,B,C,...} and the men {a,b,c...} If you choose {A,B,C} as your triple but then choose {D,a}, say, amongst the other 12, that's the same as if you first chose {A,B,D} for the triple of women and then chose {C,a}.

Comment: To clarify: you mean give $5$ different positions to $5$ out of a given set of $15$ people...? (You don't give the same position to multiple people, right?)

Comment: Correct, Rory. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is not okay (see comment of @lulu).

Answer on question 1):

$$\left[\binom{8}{3}\binom{7}{2}+\binom{8}{4}\binom{7}{1}+\binom{8}{5}\binom{7}{0}\right]5!$$

Do you see why? E.g. $\binom{8}{4}\binom71$ represents in how many ways $4$ women and $1$ men can be selected. If $5$ persons are selected then there are $5!$ ways to divide the jobs among them. This corresponds with factor $5!$.

Answer on question 2):

$$\left[\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{2}+\binom{8}{2}\binom{7}{1}\right]3!$$

Same way of thinking.

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that the author means that #2 provides additional constraints.  So you still have 5 jobs to fill, still need to hire 3 women, but you can't put women in all three of (1,3,5).

Comment: @lulu Maybe. I go for "on how many ways can the jobs 1,3 and 5 be given...". The OP will hopefully make things clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, lulu and drhab, I see where screwed up. Question 2 doesn't carry the constraint from question 1 (or at least that's how I interpret it).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Really?  But then it should be considerably easier than question 1.  As my comment to the original problem points out, there is a flaw in your solution to #1, but the same techniques that work for #1 should work for this version of #2.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having trouble understanding how to get the result from drhab, I was trying to get the total and substract the unwanted cases but I couldn't get those values...

Comment: You can do it that way, but I don't believe it's any easier.  For part #1, say, you'd start by counting all ways to choose 5 people, then exclude those with no women, then those with only 1 woman, and then those with only 2. That's three excluded cases.  Whereas to do it head on, as drhab does, you need to count those with 5 women, those with exactly 4 women, and those with exactly 3 women.  Still three cases.

Comment: As an example, let's count the cases with exactly 4 women.  In that case, you need to choose your 4 women of course...well, there are $\binom{8}{4} $ ways to do that (by definition really).  Then you need to pick a man, and there are 7 ways to do that, well $\binom{7}{1}$ if you want to be general. Thus there are exactly $\binom{8}{4} $$\binom{7}{1} $ ways to choose 5 people from your group if you insist on having exactly 4 women.  That's the middle term in drhab's sum!  the other cases are similar (simpler, even, if you look at the case of 5 women).

Comment: Thanks Lulu I got it (very thorough explanation)!. About question two, why is there a $3!$? How did drhab got that answer?

Comment: You need one woman and two men or two women and one man for the jobs
1,3 and 5. There are $\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select $1$
woman and $2$ men and there are $\binom{8}{2}\binom{7}{1}$ ways
to select $2$ women and $1$ man. After selecting the jobs 1,3 and
5 are divided over the $3$ selected persons. This can be done on
$3!$ ways.